# Nuget pre-release version, is it safe to use?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget

Is it safe to install and use on PRODUCTION a pre-release package from Nuget?

I'm interested in http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/1.1.0-alpha1 which is pre-release version. this package allows to optimize css/js files when bundling those files.

Shall I wait for the stable version or can I safely use this version?

What are the disadvantages (if any) when using  pre-release version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to use it for - for production code, I don't think I would do this, I would search for another package that can do the same thing until it is out of beta - err - alpha, and beta. For less important things, why not.